# When I run train.py with YOLACT, I get the error KeyError: 0

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm new to machine learning and program.
Now I'm trying to develop YOLACT AI using my own data.
However, when I run train.py, I get the following error and cannot learn.
What can I do to overcome this error?`

```
(yolact) tmori@tmori-Lenovo-Legion-Y740-15IRHg:~/yolact$ python train.py --config=can_config  --save_interval=2000
```

```
    loading annotations into memory...
    Done (t=0.00s)
    creating index...
    index created!
    loading annotations into memory...
    Done (t=0.00s)
    creating index...
    index created!
    Initializing weights...
    Begin training!
    
    /home/tmori/yolact/utils/augmentations.py:309: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
      mode = random.choice(self.sample_options)
    /home/tmori/yolact/utils/augmentations.py:309: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
      mode = random.choice(self.sample_options)
    /home/tmori/yolact/utils/augmentations.py:309: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
      mode = random.choice(self.sample_options)
    /home/tmori/yolact/utils/augmentations.py:309: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
      mode = random.choice(self.sample_options)
    [  0]       0 || B: 4.840 | C: 16.249 | M: 4.682 | S: 2.749 | T: 28.521 || ETA: 9:18:44 || timer: 3.352
    /home/tmori/yolact/utils/augmentations.py:309: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
      mode = random.choice(self.sample_options)
    /home/tmori/yolact/utils/augmentations.py:309: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
      mode = random.choice(self.sample_options)
    /home/tmori/yolact/utils/augmentations.py:309: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
      mode = random.choice(self.sample_options)
    /home/tmori/yolact/utils/augmentations.py:309: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
      mode = random.choice(self.sample_options)
    [  1]      10 || B: 4.535 | C: 9.228 | M: 4.379 | S: 1.867 | T: 20.008 || ETA: 3:25:24 || timer: 0.864
    /home/tmori/yolact/utils/augmentations.py:309: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
      mode = random.choice(self.sample_options)
    /home/tmori/yolact/utils/augmentations.py:309: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
      mode = random.choice(self.sample_options)
    /home/tmori/yolact/utils/augmentations.py:309: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
      mode = random.choice(self.sample_options)
    /home/tmori/yolact/utils/augmentations.py:309: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
      mode = random.choice(self.sample_options)
    
    Computing validation mAP (this may take a while)...
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "train.py", line 504, in <module>
        train()
      File "train.py", line 371, in train
        compute_validation_map(epoch, iteration, yolact_net, val_dataset, log if args.log else None)
      File "train.py", line 492, in compute_validation_map
        val_info = eval_script.evaluate(yolact_net, dataset, train_mode=True)
      File "/home/tmori/yolact/eval.py", line 956, in evaluate
        prep_metrics(ap_data, preds, img, gt, gt_masks, h, w, num_crowd, dataset.ids[image_idx], detections)
      File "/home/tmori/yolact/eval.py", line 427, in prep_metrics
        detections.add_bbox(image_id, classes[i], boxes[i,:],   box_scores[i])
      File "/home/tmori/yolact/eval.py", line 315, in add_bbox
        'category_id': get_coco_cat(int(category_id)),
      File "/home/tmori/yolact/eval.py", line 293, in get_coco_cat
        return coco_cats[transformed_cat_id]
    KeyError: 0
```

I'm trying to develop an AI that finds cans and segments them.
First I annotated only one item of "can" with labelme, and then created a COCO format json file with labelme2coco.py.
After that, I modified config.py according to "Custom Datasets" on YOLACT's GitHub and ran train.py.

My development environment is as follows.
OS:Ubuntu20.04LTS　
Anaconda:4.8.3
Python: 3.6.12
Pytorch: 1.4.0
CUDA Toolkit: 10.1
cuDNN: 7.6.5

Comment: Coco category ID is 1-based I think. Did you configure it correctly (check config.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class id in annotations.json should start from 1 not 0. If they are starting from 0, try this in config.py in your "my_custom_dataset" in label map add this

```
'label_map': { 0:  1, 1:  2, 2:  3... and so on}
```

In this case there 3 classes!

Also in yolact_base_config in same script num_classes should be 1 greater than your number of classes for example in this case it would be 4.

Comment: Thank you for your advice!
I immediately changed the "label_map" part in config.py, and ran train.py again.
But I got the same error.

I checked the train.json and test.json files again, but the category is only "can".
And the "id" of "can" is 0.

Comment: that id should be 1 not 0,. If you use the steps mentioned in https://github.com/dbolya/yolact/issues/70#issuecomment-504283008 and the labels.txt should have __ignore__ and __background__ in it and the 3rd line should be can. You can also check this link https://www.immersivelimit.com/tutorials/train-yolact-with-a-custom-coco-dataset

Comment: Thank you again for your advice!
Using the URL information you gave me, I recreated label.txt and annotated it.
And I confirmed that the "id" of "categories" of "can" of train.json and test.json was changed to 1.

However, I still encounter the error "return coco_cats [transformed_cat_id] KeyError: 1" ...

The contents of "DATASET" in config.py are as follows.
'class_names': ('can'),
'label_map': {1: 1}

Comment: In line 661 of the orginal config.py change <'num_classes': len(coco2017_dataset.class_names) + 1,> to  <num_classes': 2,>

Comment: Yes, I changed it immediately.
But I got the same error.

Comment: See this. https://github.com/dbolya/yolact/issues/67 Maybe your pytorch version is a mismatch. I used Pytorch 1.3

Comment: I installed Pytorch versions 1.3.1 and 1.2.0 using Anaconda and tried again.
At this time, I also installed CUDA and cuDNN with the command of conda.
Still, I got the same error.

I have gathered information on various websites about this error.
However, few people seemed to encounter this error.

Comment: Oh can you write the train info and test info here? maybe theres a directory issue? Annotations.json already have the image path from that folder so if you dont change anything your paths should look like images: a/b/c/train/ and info: a/b/c/train/annotations.json. Annotations and those JPEG images folder(these two) should be in same folder

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake using stackoverflow ...
I uploaded the contents of train.json at the top of the page.
I've also included additional information about the DATASETS part of config.json.

Answer (score 0):

The train.json I prepared is below.
test.json has almost the same content.

> {"info": {"description": null, "url": null, "version": null, "year": 2020, "contributor": null, "date_created": "2020-10-22 17:03:01.164640"}, "licenses": [{"url": null, "id": 0, "name": null}], "images": [{"license": 0, "url": null, "file_name": "1v6s4.jpg", "height": 640, "width": 480, "date_captured": null, "id": 0}, {"license": 0, "url": null, "file_name": "11aaw.jpg", "height": 640, "width": 480, "date_captured": null, "id": 1}, {"license": 0, "url": null, "file_name": "a255r.jpg", "height": 640, "width": 480, "date_captured": null, "id": 2}, {"license": 0, "url": null, "file_name": "3ww4h.jpg", "height": 640, "width": 480, "date_captured": null, "id": 3}, {"license": 0, "url": null, "file_name": "crgm5.jpg", "height": 640, "width": 480, "date_captured": null, "id": 4}, {"license": 0, "url": null, "file_name": "hh00w.jpg", "height": 640, "width": 480, "date_captured": null, "id": 5}, {"license": 0, "url": null, "file_name": "60fwn.jpg", "height": 640, "width": 480, "date_captured": null, "id": 6}, {"license": 0, "url": null, "file_name": "5umjh.jpg", "height": 640, "width": 480, "date_captured": null, "id": 7}, {"license": 0, "url": null, "file_name": "as8ox.jpg", "height": 640, "width": 480, "date_captured": null, "id": 8}, {"license": 0, "url": null, "file_name": "cyu14.jpg", "height": 640, "width": 480, "date_captured": null, "id": 9}], "type": "instances", "annotations": [{"id": 0, "image_id": 0, "category_id": 1, "segmentation": [[276.12582781456956, 190.39072847682118, 129.10596026490066, 224.16556291390728, 108.57615894039736, 237.41059602649005, 90.6953642384106, 267.87417218543044, 87.38410596026489, 306.94701986754967, 92.01986754966885, 345.3576158940397, 115.19867549668874, 387.7417218543046, 146.98675496688742, 416.21854304635764, 178.7748344370861, 433.4370860927152, 231.09271523178808, 426.1523178807947, 335.06622516556286, 343.3708609271523, 367.51655629139077, 299.0, 368.841059602649, 277.8079470198675, 378.77483443708604, 261.9139072847682, 378.1125827814569, 236.74834437086093, 358.90728476821187, 213.56953642384107, 333.7417218543046, 207.60927152317882, 308.57615894039736, 193.7019867549669]], "area": 50785.0, "bbox": [87.0, 190.0, 292.0, 244.0], "iscrowd": 0}, {"id": 1, "image_id": 1, "category_id": 1, "segmentation": [[252.28476821192055, 218.20529801324503, 195.99337748344368, 226.1523178807947, 157.58278145695363, 249.9933774834437, 129.76821192052978, 279.1324503311258, 115.86092715231786, 312.2450331125828, 117.84768211920527, 365.2251655629139, 132.41721854304637, 400.3245033112583, 176.78807947019868, 495.6887417218543, 201.95364238410593, 509.5960264900662, 231.09271523178808, 515.5562913907285, 256.2582781456954, 514.8940397350993, 281.42384105960264, 499.6622516556291, 370.16556291390725, 388.4039735099338, 380.0993377483444, 346.01986754966885, 373.47682119205297, 299.6622516556291, 340.36423841059604, 253.3046357615894, 293.34437086092714, 224.16556291390728]], "area": 58133.0, "bbox": [115.0, 218.0, 266.0, 298.0], "iscrowd": 0}, {"id": 2, "image_id": 2, "category_id": 1, "segmentation": [[190.6953642384106, 175.82119205298014, 169.50331125827813, 172.50993377483442, 148.31125827814571, 178.47019867549668, 130.43046357615896, 191.71523178807948, 120.49668874172187, 212.24503311258277, 117.18543046357615, 230.78807947019868, 121.15894039735099, 248.66887417218544, 201.95364238410593, 371.8476821192053, 221.8211920529801, 392.3774834437086, 235.0662251655629, 407.6092715231788, 253.6092715231788, 415.55629139072846, 276.12582781456956, 414.89403973509934, 306.5894039735099, 400.9867549668874, 328.44370860927154, 379.79470198675494, 343.67549668874176, 355.95364238410593, 348.3112582781457, 330.12582781456956, 343.67549668874176, 310.9205298013245, 332.4172185430464, 297.6754966887417, 319.1721854304636, 279.1324503311258]], "area": 32819.0, "bbox": [117.0, 172.0, 232.0, 244.0], "iscrowd": 0}, {"id": 3, "image_id": 3, "category_id": 1, "segmentation": [[301.95364238410593, 155.2913907284768, 285.3973509933775, 157.27814569536423, 274.1390728476821, 164.56291390728478, 272.81456953642385, 173.83443708609272, 268.1788079470199, 180.4569536423841, 264.20529801324506, 297.0132450331126, 284.07284768211923, 310.2582781456954, 303.2781456953643, 310.9205298013245, 322.48344370860923, 300.9867549668874, 336.3907284768212, 191.05298013245033, 334.40397350993373, 182.4437086092715, 333.7417218543046, 168.53642384105962, 321.158940397351, 159.9271523178808]], "area": 9448.0, "bbox": [264.0, 155.0, 73.0, 156.0], "iscrowd": 0}, {"id": 4, "image_id": 3, "category_id": 1, "segmentation": [[143.01324503311258, 315.55629139072846, 122.48344370860929, 320.8543046357616, 110.56291390728478, 332.7748344370861, 105.26490066225165, 347.34437086092714, 105.26490066225165, 353.3046357615894, 104.60264900662253, 362.57615894039736, 141.02649006622516, 468.5364238410596, 156.25827814569539, 472.50993377483445, 179.43708609271522, 469.19867549668874, 192.68211920529802, 461.25165562913907, 197.9801324503311, 444.6953642384106, 182.08609271523176, 342.7086092715232, 177.4503311258278, 338.07284768211923, 170.82781456953643, 324.82781456953643, 157.58278145695363, 317.5430463576159]], "area": 10548.0, "bbox": [104.0, 315.0, 94.0, 158.0], "iscrowd": 0}, {"id": 5, "image_id": 4, "category_id": 1, "segmentation": [[321.158940397351, 231.4503311258278, 111.88741721854302, 310.9205298013245, 95.99337748344368, 330.12582781456956, 99.96688741721852, 358.6026490066225, 117.84768211920527, 398.3377483443709, 137.71523178807945, 428.80132450331126, 142.35099337748346, 432.112582781457, 170.1655629139073, 434.7615894039735, 365.5298013245033, 334.7615894039735, 375.46357615894044, 310.9205298013245, 372.1523178807947, 282.44370860927154, 356.2582781456954, 252.64238410596028, 336.3907284768212, 234.76158940397352]], "area": 33580.0, "bbox": [95.0, 231.0, 281.0, 204.0], "iscrowd": 0}, {"id": 6, "image_id": 5, "category_id": 1, "segmentation": [[235.72847682119203, 177.1456953642384, 182.74834437086093, 183.10596026490066, 185.39735099337747, 189.0662251655629, 178.11258278145698, 217.54304635761588, 177.4503311258278, 465.887417218543, 188.7086092715232, 473.8344370860927, 220.49668874172187, 478.4701986754967, 257.5827814569536, 477.1456953642384, 290.0331125827814, 467.2119205298013, 294.6688741721854, 218.20529801324503, 286.7218543046357, 194.36423841059602, 290.69536423841055, 184.43046357615893]], "area": 33720.0, "bbox": [177.0, 177.0, 118.0, 302.0], "iscrowd": 0}, {"id": 7, "image_id": 6, "category_id": 1, "segmentation": [[185.39735099337747, 210.25827814569536, 156.9205298013245, 211.58278145695365, 127.78145695364236, 222.17880794701986, 119.83443708609269, 241.3841059602649, 122.48344370860929, 251.31788079470198, 115.19867549668874, 273.17218543046357, 130.43046357615896, 471.8476821192053, 145.0, 491.05298013245033, 173.47682119205297, 496.35099337748346, 203.27814569536423, 494.36423841059604, 220.49668874172187, 485.0927152317881, 227.11920529801324, 473.8344370860927, 251.62251655629137, 271.8476821192053, 246.3245033112583, 262.57615894039736, 248.31125827814571, 242.04635761589404, 239.03973509933775, 224.16556291390728, 212.5496688741722, 214.2317880794702]], "area": 32447.0, "bbox": [115.0, 210.0, 137.0, 287.0], "iscrowd": 0}, {"id": 8, "image_id": 7, "category_id": 1, "segmentation": [[240.36423841059604, 157.94039735099338, 213.21192052980132, 163.23841059602648, 200.6291390728477, 166.5496688741722, 204.60264900662253, 177.80794701986756, 203.27814569536423, 181.11920529801324, 203.94039735099335, 185.09271523178808, 200.6291390728477, 198.33774834437085, 202.6158940397351, 200.32450331125827, 204.60264900662253, 215.5562913907285, 192.01986754966885, 229.46357615894038, 172.81456953642385, 273.17218543046357, 180.76158940397352, 471.18543046357615, 183.41059602649005, 477.1456953642384, 182.74834437086093, 482.44370860927154, 203.94039735099335, 500.3245033112583, 237.71523178807945, 504.96026490066225, 276.7880794701987, 500.3245033112583, 297.9801324503311, 492.3774834437086, 303.2781456953643, 478.4701986754967, 301.95364238410593, 471.8476821192053, 307.2516556291391, 463.9006622516556, 307.91390728476824, 266.5496688741722, 292.0198675496689, 228.80132450331126, 280.7615894039735, 215.5562913907285, 282.7483443708609, 210.9205298013245, 278.1125827814569, 202.3112582781457, 280.0993377483444, 195.02649006622516, 280.7615894039735, 163.90066225165563, 250.96026490066225, 158.60264900662253]], "area": 40240.0, "bbox": [172.0, 157.0, 136.0, 348.0], "iscrowd": 0}, {"id": 9, "image_id": 8, "category_id": 1, "segmentation": [[243.01324503311258, 165.2251655629139, 214.53642384105962, 169.86092715231788, 195.33112582781456, 177.80794701986756, 181.42384105960264, 187.74172185430464, 176.78807947019868, 206.28476821192052, 180.0993377483444, 210.25827814569536, 172.81456953642385, 224.82781456953643, 187.3841059602649, 449.33112582781456, 197.9801324503311, 469.19867549668874, 227.11920529801324, 480.4569536423841, 249.63576158940396, 481.11920529801324, 272.1523178807947, 473.8344370860927, 289.3708609271523, 457.94039735099335, 323.8079470198676, 228.80132450331126, 319.83443708609275, 218.86754966887418, 319.83443708609275, 204.2980132450331, 313.2119205298013, 189.0662251655629, 294.00662251655626, 175.158940397351, 270.8278145695364, 169.86092715231788]], "area": 38543.0, "bbox": [172.0, 165.0, 152.0, 317.0], "iscrowd": 0}, {"id": 10, "image_id": 9, "category_id": 1, "segmentation": [[122.48344370860929, 283.10596026490066, 100.62913907284769, 287.7417218543046, 82.08609271523181, 302.3112582781457, 78.7748344370861, 311.5827814569536, 82.08609271523181, 327.47682119205297, 154.9337748344371, 447.34437086092714, 170.1655629139073, 447.34437086092714, 205.26490066225165, 422.841059602649, 211.88741721854302, 408.27152317880797, 135.72847682119203, 291.05298013245033]], "area": 11069.0, "bbox": [78.0, 283.0, 134.0, 165.0], "iscrowd": 0}, {"id": 11, "image_id": 9, "category_id": 1, "segmentation": [[383.4105960264901, 249.33112582781456, 370.8278145695364, 245.35761589403972, 355.59602649006627, 246.01986754966887, 337.05298013245033, 258.6026490066225, 337.05298013245033, 266.5496688741722, 351.62251655629143, 384.43046357615896, 358.90728476821187, 392.3774834437086, 380.0993377483444, 393.03973509933775, 402.61589403973505, 385.7549668874172, 409.2384105960265, 378.4701986754967, 388.04635761589407, 256.6158940397351]], "area": 7924.0, "bbox": [337.0, 245.0, 73.0, 149.0], "iscrowd": 0}], "categories": [{"supercategory": null, "id": 0, "name": "*background*"}, {"supercategory": null, "id": 1, "name": "can"}]}

I used the git clone command to install yolact in my home directory.
My PC's directory structure is as follows:

/home/user-name/yolact/cans/cans_train/train.json and images

/home/user-name/yolact/cans/cans_test/test.json and images

Finally, I set --DATASETS-- in config.py as follows.

```
cans_dataset = dataset_base.copy({
'name': 'cans_dataset',

'train_images': './cans/cans_train/',
'train_info':   './cans/cans_train/train.json',

'valid_images': './cans/cans_test/',
'valid_info':   './cans/cans_test/test.json',

'has_gt': True,
'class_names': ('can'),
'label_map':  { 1: 1}
```

And I set --YOLACT v1.0 CONFIGS-- in config.py as follows.

```
cans_config = yolact_darknet53_config.copy({
'name': 'cans',

'dataset': cans_dataset,
'num_classes': len(cans_dataset.class_names) + 1,

'max_size': 500,

# Training params
'lr_steps': (8000, 9000),
'max_iter': 10000,
```

})

Comment: can you also show your -- YOLACT v1.0 CONFIGS --? 
It should be......'dataset': my_custom_dataset, 'num_classes': len(my_custom_dataset.class_names) + 1, or just 2. LIke this is mine you can set it to your specific names.

Comment: I added the information of -YOLACT v1.0 CONFIGS- that I set myself.